# AdMob7.5.2/iOSでの広告表示異常

Tags: ios, admob

環境: Xcode7.1,AdMob7.5.2/iOS9.1, AdMob Mediationで、AdMobとiAdの広告2本立て
　　　iOS Simulator.iPhone App.

simulator環境では、iAdは、テスト用の広告。AdMobでは、実際の広告を出すことが出来ます。
 banner size は、kGADBannerSizeを指定。

この時、simulatorで、対象モデルをiPhoneシリーズで、変更しても、iAdのダミー広告は、破綻がありません。しかし、AdMob側では、iPhone4Sでは、破綻がありませんが、iPhone5以降では、明らかに、表示領域より大きなイメージが、AdMob サーバーから降ってきていて、右側と下側が欠ける表示が出ますけど、これは、AdMobのバグなんでしょうか？

BannerのUIViewは、IBで、貼付け、制約子は、縦50で、幅は指定なしで、leadingとtrailingは、それぞれSuperviewのそれぞれとequalです。これが、まずいのですかね。

Comment: その後、判明したのは、leadingとtrailingの制約子を除去し、width=320の制約子をつけると、AdMob側は、左右に余白は出ますが、正しく表示されます。しかし、この場合、今度は、iAd側が、左右で、表示が切られます。

Comment: 更にわかったこと。
1. kGADSizeBanner指定で、BannerViewの領域を、320x50に、、制約子で、制限した場合、AdMob側は、どのデバイスモデルでも、問題がない。iAd側は、iPhone5以降のモデルでは、両側の端が切られた表示になる。

2. iAdは、AdMobの指定がなんであろうと、イメージは、縦50,幅はデバイスのサイズで、降ってくるので、正しく表示される為には、幅のサイズに制約子はつけてはいけない。leading,trailingをsuperviewのそれぞれと一致させる表示できる。しかし、こういう設定では、AdMob側は正しく表示されない。

3. kGADSizeSmartBannerPortlaitの指定をAdMob側ですると、AdMobは、デバイスの画面縦サイスに従って、バナーサイズを変更できるが、縦720ピクセル以上のデバイスでは、縦90のバナーになる。この時、iAdは、縦90のイメージは、落としてこないみたいだ。


　ということで、2本立て表示で、iPhone全モデル対応するのは、簡単ではないような。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局、わかったのは

1. AdMobの場合、Simulatorで、テスト広告設定をしたときと、そうでない設定では、サイズが、kGADSizeBannerのとき、振舞いが異なる。
2. テスト広告設定の場合（シミュレータID使用時）は、320x50のダミー広告が表示される。表示領域が広い場合は、左右に余白がでる。
3. テスト広告設定でない場合、シミュレータでも本物の広告が降ってくるが、これは、表示領域の広さによって、320x50でないことがある。その為、iPhone6以降だと、下か右端が欠ける表示になる。もともと、Googleは、シミュレータでは、ダミー広告を使え、といっているので、これは、目的外使用であるが。
4. iAdは、AdMob側の指定がなんであろうと、縦50,幅一杯の、広告が降ってくる。
5. AdMob側のスマートバナーは、幅は、iAdと同じく、通しであるが、縦サイズは、スクリーンの縦サイズによって、変化する。現在でているiPhoneでは、iPhone6+ iphone6s+では、iAdと縦サイズが異なる縦90の指定になる。すなわち、iAd広告表示の時には、かなり目に付く余白ができる。
6. AdMob MediationのAPIには、これから出す広告ネットワークがどのネットワークから来ているのか、知る術はないので、プログラムで、表示領域のサイズをダイナミックに変更は出来そうもない。

   ということで、AdMob/iAd両対応を、すべてのiPhoneモデルで、余白がでないように表示するのは、いまのところ出来ないようです。